# Firebase getDownloadURL with multiple files

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

We have a simple web app where users log in via firebase authentication and then have access to a portal. In that portal, there are docs that only logged-in users are supposed to see. Our problem is that we had those files stored outside of firebase storage, so if someone had the file URL, they could see the files without being logged in.

We've added the files to a "docs" folder in firebase storage. We've changed the links in our html to the "gs" file location. We are having trouble getting the download url to work using firebase example code.

Here's what we have so far...

```
/ Create a storage reference from our storage service
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var imagesRef = storageRef.child('docs');
var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://bucketname.appspot.com/docs/2FNATGEN_HOME.doc')
storageRef.child('docs/2FNATGEN_HOME.doc').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
 // This can be downloaded directly:
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(event) {
  var blob = xhr.response;
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();

// Or inserted into an <img> element:
var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
// Handle any errors
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. One thing I know we are confused about is that the sample code seems designed to work with one file. We are more of a "google drive" scenario where logged in users need to access to lots of files.

Thank you!

Comment: The only variables you're using to get the download URL, of all that you've defined, are `storageRef` and `fileName`.  Everything else is unused.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Doug - no not at all. I was simply copying an pasting code from the examples on the firebase wesbite and trying to get it to work.